# Simplexml: Select element by id a echo a certain child element

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I'd need some advise with simplexml xpath. I have a master XML-file for my entire website like this:

```
<content>
<item id="001">
    <title>Video 1</title>
    <video>
        <file>video001.mp4</file>
        <dur>01:20</dur>
    </video>
</item>
<item id="2">
    <title>Video 2</title>
    <video>
        <file>video002.mp4</file>
        **<dur>03:53</dur>**
    </video>
</item>
</content>
```

Now I want to echo the duration of the video of item with the id "2" which would be the string "03:53".

Seems to be the simples use of simplexml, but the tons of tutorials out there only cover loops and selection by array number. I want to access a parent element by its id an grab the string of a certain child element of it.

Thanks in advance!
Runa

Answer (score 1):

You may use XPath for that purpose:
http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

You code should look like this (more or less):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('path/to/xml/file.xml');
$result = $xml->xpath('/content/item[@id=2]/video/dur/text()');
$result = $result[0];
echo $result;
```

Here is phpFiddle http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9hc-yqi

Probably you should also cast xpath result on string but I'm not sure. I just tested xpath part of this code inside http://www.xpathtester.com/ and it works just fine.

Comment: in PHP >= 5.4, you can do $result = $xml->xpath('/content/item[@id=2]/video/dur')[0]; and delete the next line.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work properly. I get an empty response, instead of the string. Omitting the line $result = $result[0]; gives me 'Array'.

Comment: Probably your PHP version is below 5.4 which is very common unless you have most recent WAMP/XAMP version (I assume you are on localhost). Btw. please accept my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: PHP Version 5.4.9 and SimpleXML enabled on my real webserver. The above mentioned xpathtester says 'nothing found' (http://www.xpathtester.com/obj/6d59e412-6334-40b0-a0e6-6b480242cea3). SimpleXML is not as simple as I thought :)

Comment: The [@id=...] seems to be the problem. It causes the same troubles in a phptester when I replace [0] by that in other scripts.

Comment: The [@id=...] has turned out as the problem. IDs with integers like '0123' work, but letters as 'one' do not work.

Comment: did you try [@id='some_letters'] ? (in quotes)